# Subquery and concatenation in hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive, subquery

I am trying to concatenate a String and the output of a subquery in hive. it is throwing an  error over using the pipe for concatenation. My query is as follows.

```
select id, ('hello:' || (select distinct(name) from abc c1 where c1.id=c2.id and balanc=(select max(balanc) from abc  where c1.id=c2.id)) as description from pqr c2;
```

Below is the error stack:

> cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification

I am quite new here. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first specify the table structure of table abc & pqr ?

Comment: Table structure is as follows: abc(name, balanc, id) and pqr (id)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to concat a string & use subquery try below :
SELECT id,name,balanc FROM( SELECT c1.id as id,c1.name as name,c1.balanc as balanc FROM pql c2 JOIN abc c1 WHERE c1.id=c2.id) t2;

Somehow you cannot use aggregation function in subquery like MAX when you are returning more then 1 column in result. If you only want to find out max value out of subquery you can try below query

SELECT balanc FROM( SELECT MAX(c1.balanc) as balanc FROM pql c2 JOIN abc c1 WHERE c1.id=c2.id) t2

Hope this helps you.. Good luck!!

Comment: But I have to concatenate a the query output to a String as well.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to apply concat function. try below : 

SELECT id,name,balanc FROM( SELECT c1.id as id,CONCAT("HELLO:",c1.name) as name,c1.balanc as balanc FROM pql c2 JOIN abc c1 WHERE c1.id=c2.id) t2;

Comment: if join doesn't work try below command too.
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;

Comment: I have to find the name of the person with max balance and the output of that query will become the description in the outer table. For description, I am adding a string before creating it. For example, "hello aparna" is the description. But here aparna is having max balance which is present in abc and also in pqr.

Comment: try this. : SELECT collect_set(id),collect_set(CONCAT("Hello:",name)) as desc,max(balanc) from abc

Comment: Bhavesh, I just want two fields i.e. Id and description. And Description should be the combo of the string "Hello" and the name of the person with max balance and whose id exits in another id table i.e. pqr. Also, Id here should belong to pqr table as well.